# Does DEVELOPER_DIR need to remain set in the environment?

Tags: xcode, macos, environment-variables, clang, xcrun

I'd like to have side-by-side installations of XCode, and use the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable to select between them. The goal for this is to use the result of `xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang` to determine the appropriate C compiler, and then use that in a script or build system.

`CC=$(DEVELOPER_DIR=<something> xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang)`

My question is whether `DEVELOPER_DIR` needs to remain set when *using* the tools found by `xcrun`, or whether it is OK to just set it during the execution of `xcrun`, as is done above, and then use the returned tools in the default environment, without `DEVELOPER_DIR` still set.

In other words, while `xcrun` clearly does depend on the value of `DEVELOPER_DIR`, do the tools themselves depend on it too? Is there a meaningful difference between:

- `DEVELOPER_DIR=<whatever> command CC=$(xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang)`
- `command CC=$(DEVELOPER_DIR=<whatever> xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang)`

Is the second one correct? Or only the first?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to have side-by-side installations of XCode, and use the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable to select between them.

It's fine to have two or more versions of Xcode installed. The usual way to select between them is to use the `xcode-select` command, but the man page for that command does seem to say that you can accomplish the same thing for just the current session by setting the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable yourself. Here's what the documentation for the `--switch` option says:

> *Sets the active developer directory to the given path, for example
>   /Applications/Xcode-DP.app. This command must be  run with superuser
>   permissions (see sudo(8)), and will affect all users on the system. To
>   set the path with-out superuser permissions or only for the current
>   shell session,  use  the  DEVELOPER_DIR  environment variable instead
>   (see ENVIRONMENT).*

However, you should also heed the advice given in the ENVIRONMENT section:

> *Note that for historical reason, the developer directory is considered
>   to be the Developer content directory inside the Xcode application
>   (for example /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer). You can set
>   the environment variable to either the actual Developer contents
>   directory, or the Xcode application directory -- the code-select
>   provided shims will automatically convert the environment variable
>   into the full Developer content path.*

So the `<whatever>` in your question should specify the full path to the `Developer` directory, not just to the Xcode application.

> In other words, while xcrun clearly does depend on the value of DEVELOPER_DIR, do the tools themselves depend on it too? Is there a meaningful difference between:
>
> • `DEVELOPER_DIR=<whatever> command CC=$(xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang)`

Using `xcrun` to find the tools so that you can invoke them yourself and worrying about when to set and unset `DEVELOPER_DIR` seems overly complicated. Per the `xcode-select` documentation, all the "shims" respect the `DEVELOPER_DIR` setting. "Shims" here refers to the Xcode commands in `/usr/bin`. As long as that environment variable is set correctly, you can just invoke '/usr/bin/clang' instead of whatever `xcrun` finds, and `/usr/bin/clang` will call through to the `clang` version in `DEVELOPER_DIR`. Presumably, you're asking this question because you're writing a build script of some kind, so there should be no problem setting `DEVELOPER_DIR` early in that script and then just using the `/usr/bin` commands.

> • `command CC=$(DEVELOPER_DIR=<whatever> xcrun -f --sdk macosx clang)`

Programs inherit the environment from their parent processes. Here you're finding the right copy of `clang` to use, but you'll invoke it in an environment where `DEVELOPER_DIR` isn't set. Whether this matters depends on whether the tool you're using invokes any other tools. I honestly don't know whether any of the tools do invoke other tools, but it seems logical that a tool like `xcodebuild` would invoke many of those tools and therefore depend on `DEVELOPER_DIR` being set correctly.

In short, there's no downside to setting `DEVELOPER_DIR` as needed in your build script, and trying to specify it only in your call to `xcrun` seems less reliable in general than the alternative approach.